# Metal puzzle - Spiral and Triangle with U-Shape; Triangle with Ring at the beginning

Tags: mechanical-puzzles, solvability

I got the puzzle from [here](https://de.aliexpress.com/item/32473415899.html). Here is a picture of it:

[image: Spiral and Triangle with U-Shape; Triangle with Ring at the beginning]

How is it possible to solve it?

---

**UPDATE:** Thanks @JaapScherphuis - this is the solution:

> [image: Spiral and Triangle with U-Shape; Triangle with Ring at the beginning] [image: Spiral and Triangle with U-Shape; Triangle with Ring at the beginning]

Comment: Here is an older question with [generic solving method](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62266/general-strategies-for-solving-metal-disentanglement-puzzles/62282#62282) for these kinds of puzzles.

Comment: the lenght of the parallel part of the "heart" seems close to the diameter of the inner part of the spiral (without the outer ring), it is suspicious that you might have to use this fact somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot be certain without physically attempting.

However, I can posit a solution...
Step 1:

> It appears that the U-shape in the middle of the triangle should fit in the hole at the top left of the spiral.
>  [image]

Step 2:

> Loop it through the spiral until it gets to the center.  Then follow the opposite path out.

Why:

> Since the wire is now on the "outside" of the spiral then it will be removed.

Comment: Thanks, but i dont think this works or i cant implement this one . I will post a picture of my current situation

Comment: @user64969 The puzzle consists of the small ring, which has a stem that goes around in a loop, through the ring, and then spirals inward. The part you need to remove needs to follow that stem and dip into the ring. On your photo you are approaching the ring from the side that the stem sprouts from, but you should be going in from the other side which is where the stem dips into the ring.

Comment: thanks. i am now really near the middle of the loop. but again i am stuck :( -> Photo in the question

Comment: @user64969 Read the comment above yours here.

Comment: sorry i was just delayed uploading the new photo, i have read it already

Comment: @user64969 You don't need to go into the spiral section. Think of the spiral inside the outer ring as a solid disc. Your moving loop piece just has to go around the outside of this disc, and then back out the ring again.

Comment: i cant really go through this ring, because the top of the triangel fits only about 2cm and the U-Shape from the triangel can only fit as shown in the last picture

Comment: @ Jaap Scherphuis , the problem was i had to sqeeze the U-Shape from the triangel around the spiral. Thanks so much for your answers =)

Answer (score 0):

The trick with these such puzzles is to take the thin "U" shape in the centre of the removeable piece, and thread it through the small "o" joining the enclosing piece, before looping it around the maze to the other side of the "o" where it can be removed. The below puzzle is a slightly different shape, but it is essentially the same solution:

[image]

- [Basic Strategies to solve Disentanglement Puzzles](https://www.gathering4gardner.org/g4g11gift/Gotz_Markus-Disentanglement_Puzzles.pdf), Markus Götz